# Ansible - How to skip registering a variable if the when condition is not met

Tags: ansible

```
-  shell: "echo 'hi'"
   register: output
-  shell: "ps -ef"
   register: output
   when: output.stdout =="hello"
 - debug: var=output
```

The final output variable is defined as below:

```
TASK [Display output] **********************************************************

    ok: [localhost] => 
{
    "output": 
   {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

Even though the task 2 is skipped, the variable gets registered. How can I skip the register if the condition is not met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register both outcomes as output1 and output2. Use 'set_fact' to set a new variable 'output' according to your condition.

```
- shell: "echo 'hi'"
  register: output1
- shell: "ps -ef"
  register: output2
- set_fact:
    output: "{{ output2 if output2.stdout =='hello' | default(output1)}}"
- debug: var=output
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"How can I skip the register if the condition is not met?"***

A: You can't. Quoting from [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables):

> *"Note: If a task fails or is skipped, the variable still is registered with a failure or skipped status, the only way to avoid registering a variable is using tags."*

Answer (score 0):

@Uttams answer didn't work for me. I suspect because of the `|` condition in `set_fact`. Instead, the following works in my case:

```yaml
- shell: "echo 'hi'"
  register: output1
- shell: "ps -ef"
  register: output2
- set_fact:
    output: "{{ output2 if output2.stdout is defined else output1 }}"
- debug: var=output
```

The latter variable is chosen if it's `output` attribute is defined. This is only the case if the task has not been skipped.
This logic can be expanded with more `ifelse` blocks if needed.